# How to use 'people' and 'they'

Tags: word-choice

I am not a native speaker and I get confused with the use of the words 'people' and 'they'. Do the following sentences mean the same?

> When people heard the news, the bravest volunteers came forward with
>   help.
>
> When they heard the news, the bravest volunteers came forward with
>   help.

Can we use 'they' in front of the noun phrase as in the second sentence?

Comment: Yes; that's correct.

Comment: Lee, you might consider looking on [ell.se] for guidance on future questions.

Comment: Is there any difference in meaning between these two sentences? I am not sure about the referents of the word 'people' and 'they'. Does 'people' refer to everyone and 'they' refer to 'the bravest volunteers'? Thank you.

Comment: That should go into the question. Most will miss it if you post it as a comment. Please edit.

Comment: Yes, we can use. The sentences may or may not mean the same depending on the broader context.

Answer (score 1):

I would add that 'they' is more specific than 'people'.
In the first sentence, all the people within a certain definition, class, or area heard the news but the bravest volunteers among them came forward.
In the second sentence, 'they' refers directly to 'the bravest volunteers' who came forward because they heard the news. Whether other people also heard the news  or not (in sentence 2) is somewhat irrelevant.

Comment: @Lee If you like an answer, upvote it by clicking the up-arrow to the left of the answer. After at least a day or so (enough time for people in various time zones to participate), if you are particularly happy with one of the answers, award it the green tick. It should be to the left of the answer as well. Awarding the green tick marks your question as *answered*.